# Click on Home in Android and it should logout when the time of resume is more than 4 minutes?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I wish to implement the functionality that when I click on the home of my android app while running my app and then if the user resumes again after 4 minutes, then I should logout the user and again show him the login screen or if he resumes before 4 minutes than it should show him the screen from where he left. So what can be the best way to implement this functionality.

Comment: Perhaps store a value based on current timestamp in the preferences then check to see if greater than or equal to 4 minutes (inside onResume) then do what you need to do?

Comment: How are you doing session management? You could just make your token expire after four minutes unless it gets renewed.

Comment: @Eenvincible How we will get to know whether the onResume is coming from another activity or the user is restarting the app from background. Because on changing the activity the previous activities are also in onResume. I am new to android. Sorry if something silly is being asked.

Comment: @Eric S. Yes it is the good way. But if I don't won't to hit the server and get the session. Is there some way from client side only in android.

Comment: There is something as HomeWatcher class and using the BroadcastListener, But I am not able to understand it.

Comment: I know what you are looking for, I'll write it up.

Comment: Edit actually, my solution is different. I was gonna override the home button receiver but I remembered normal apps dont have permission for this. Just stick with checking in onStop/onStart

Answer (score 1):

You can create a variable to save the time of last run in and a `boolean` variable that tells if the activity stopped because of home clicks or moving between activities.

```
private long lastRun = 0;
private boolean homeClicked = true;
```

The variable `homeClicked` is true unless you **start another activity**, then you have to **set it to false** that means the activity didn't stop because of home button click but because of moving between activities.

```
homeClicked = false;
```

then add those 2 methods to your activity

```
// this will be called when the activity stops
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    // check if the home was clicked
    if (homeClicked)
        lastRun = System.currentTimeMillis(); // save time of last run
}

// this will be called when the activity starts
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // check if it's the first run or not
    if (lastRun != 0) {
        // check if the activity stopped because of home clicked or not
        if (homeClicked) {
            if ((lastRun - System.currentTimeMillis()) / 1000 / 60 >= 4) {
                // end this activity and show login screen
            }
        } else {
            // reset its value so that you can check it again
            homeClicked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

hope it helps :)

Comment: Great solution. I have two queries. First Do I have to write this in all my activites or there is some single entry solution also. Like something from manifest.xml. Second one is, When I switch between activites then also onStop and onStart methods are called. So if I come to some activity from another activity after 4 minutes then it is the wrong functionality. It will logout the session. I am new to android, questions can be silly.

Comment: @AkshayKant ah yeah you're right. Sorry for that mistake, I've edited my code. thanks for notifying me :) unfortunately you have to add it to every activity.

Comment: Super..One more question. How can I get the reference whether the home is clicked or not?

Comment: @AkshayKant in this code you don't but if the activity doesn't stop for any other reason, the only left is home clicked :D that is `homeClicked` equals true.

Answer (score 1):

I am writing this as a answer as it is too long to be a comment. As well, this is just a broad idea on the implementation not a complete solution. You may need to have additional checks to know where onResume is coming from.

You can do that by sending additional data in intent that you create to call the subject activity.

Say, you do not want to log out if activity B calls activity A.
So, in activity B, when you start activity A. You can pass in the caller.

```
// warning pseudo code, written without compiler.
Intent i = new Intent(context, A.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle()'
b.putExtra("caller", "B");
i.putExtras(b);
startActivity(i)
```

And in activity A's onResume, you can check the intent.

```
Intent i = getIntent();
Bundle b = i.getExtras();
String caller = b.getString("caller");
if(caller!=null && caller.equals("B")){
    // Use logic as described below
}
```

Save timestamp when activity is paused like this

```
@Override
public void onStop(){
    //getting the current time in milliseconds
    Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    long millis = date.getTime();

    SharedPreferences prefs = ...;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putLong("time", date.getTime());
    editor.commit();
}

@Override
public void onStart(){
    Date myDate = new Date(prefs.getLong("time", 0));
    // Logic to check current time with saved time and logout accordingly.
}
```

**Update:**

To find out if an Activity is getting opened by the launcher you can do the following (write this code in onStart() of activity where you want the logout logic):

```
Intent i = getIntent()
if (i != null && i.getCategories() != null) {
    if (i.getCategories().contains("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER")) {
        // Activity opened by launcher
    }
}
```

Comment: onPause will trigger whenever the activity is not in focus. You probably want onStop. To be most specific to his requirement, you would overload the onHomeButtonReceiver.

Comment: I have two queries. First Do I have to write this in all my activites or there is some single entry solution also. Like something from manifest.xml. Second one is, When I switch between activites then also onStop and onStart methods are called. So if I come to some activity from another activity after 4 minutes then it is the wrong functionality. It will logout the session. I am new to android, questions can be silly

Comment: There is a intent filter to find out if the person is coming from launcher and not some other activity. That way you get to not write the bundle in all other activities. I am throwing broad ideas here :)
@EricS.: Thanks for pointing out, you are right. Let me see if I can make this edit, it is too small I think SO won't let me do it :)

Comment: @EricS.: Made the update, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Np, don't forget the onStart part too.

Comment: @EricS. done. thanks

Comment: I added the part to find if the activity is opened from launcher as well :)
@EricS.: mind a pseudo-code review ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

1. Create a service. Start it when you start your app
2. In your service create a Broadcast Listener and register it when service starts with some intent action "`my.action.for.broadcast`"
3. Send broadcast with this intent from all your activities in `onPause` with information that this activity is pausing. And, send broadcast with same intent on `onResume` methods of all your Activities that this activity is starting.
4. Keep a `Set` in your service with info that how many activities are running. Whenever, any activity sends broadcast through `onResume` , add it to the Set. If broadcast was send by `onPause`, remove that activity from Set.(hint: you can identify which activity send message by keeping that info in intent extras. Similarly you can know whether this is a 'pause' message or 'resume' message.
5. When all activities are finished from `Set`, start a `CountDownTimer`, that counts down to 4 minute.
6. If 4 minutes finished and `Set` is still empty, execute your sign out code here.

This general method is useful for detecting when your complete app goes to background.